# What is the equivalent of Vuex/Redux in EmberJS?

Tags: reactjs, ember.js, vue.js, redux, vuex

I am trying to understand why a flux architecture is required for react with redux and vue with vuex but not ember.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://github.com/ember-redux/ember-redux

https://github.com/bgentry/ember-apollo-client

The reason why vue.js & react.js requires vuex and redux is because react / vue are ui libraries and not frameworks. Ember has its own built-in system of state management (2 way data binding).

Comment: Also, services for app level state. I did a blog on this: https://www.developertown.com/react-vs-ember-part-2-state-management/

Comment: Vue is a framework, and does not require vuex - at least here in 2022.